# REST: How to handle an action changing multiple resources

Tags: rest, restful-architecture

I am trying to understand the resource-based RESTful architecture. I understand that an HTTP GET on `/accounts` will list the accounts and GET on `/accounts/123` will provide details on the given account. 
How do I implement active management in RESTful architecture, like transfer money from account A to account B?

Comment: You would have to do something with Post - send transaction information along and perform transaction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the idea of declaring the transaction itself as a resource, so that you could operate  on your single resource atomically:

```
POST /transaction

-> /transaction/456
```

I suggest avoiding `HTTP PUT` in this case because idempotency is not what we want for this resource.

Posting the new transaction will update the account A and B.